# Publishing an (.exe) application

Tags: windows, installation

I have an application and I would like to make a windows installer in order to deploy it. I'd need good and free tools in order to make a .msi. I googled a bit without any good finds :( . Thanks for anyhelp!

Answer (score 2):

**Have you looked into the [WIX toolkit](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)?**

For most installation tasks, it works quite well ... a bit underdocumented, perhaps - but it is free.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a .msi?? Could be an .exe installer?

You can try [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). Simple to use and very powerfull.

Is you .exe app made with .Net or it's a native application? InnoSetup is well suited for native apps.

Answer (score 0):

There's always [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=VS.90).aspx). As long as you're using C# or VB.NET it will do the job for you.

Comment: I tried that already. And it was creating a file setup.exe and programName.application. I dont want a .application.

Comment: @triggy - you should have mentioned that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio simply create an installer project and add it to your solution.  It allows you to create an MSI installer project with a few clicks.

If you don't have VS I would look into InnoSetup.